# whether submitting single column of a data (i have 513 columns) as a image to CNN as input is correct way?

Tags: input, data-processing

I have DNA methylation data of Lower grade glioma samples obtained from GDC data portal. the values in my data are ranging from 0 to 1. I want to do classification of these samples into two classes as IDH WT and IDH mutant.
I want to use CNN for classification purpose. Thus i am doing image embedding here to give image as input. I am new to deep learning methods. I needed help with data preparation for CNN method.  I am referring to this paper-(reference paper: doi: http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/364323.) My question is,

1. I have data frame of 9203*513 (row*column), i have saved each column into a separate file (excel file).
2. then i have reshaped each single file into 767*12 (row*column) by inserting one more row and zero is added there.
3. then i have done image embedding of each file. and i have submitted these all files to CNN as input. (training set: 80% images and test set: 20% images)

So is this approach correct to give input to CNN for classification problem?

I'm open to all suggestions,
Thank you for your time and consideration,

Comment: I am no expert in biology. But, if each column of your data frame means one sample you want to predict, I think you are correct. Is there any problem now? It would be better you provide the exact problem you faced.

Comment: Hi Hui-Po Wang,   Thank you for the response. No other problem I'm facing. I only wanted to confirm the approach to classify the two groups of samples. Thank you again :)